# Save file in an Excel add-in with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I created an Excel add-in using Yeoman Generator in TypeScript. The add-in provided some basic information such as highlighting parts of the Excel with a click of a button, calling external APIs to process cells, etc. However, when I tried to use fs or file-savers to create and download a new file, there is no error message and nothing is being downloaded. The code is shown below.

```
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import { Document, Packer, Paragraph, TextRun } from "docx";

export const docGenerator = async () => {
  // Documents contain sections, you can have multiple sections per document, go here to learn more about sections
  // This simple example will only contain one section
  const doc = new Document({
    sections: [
      {
        properties: {},
        children: [
          new Paragraph({
            children: [
              new TextRun("Hello World"),
              new TextRun({
                text: "Foo Bar",
                bold: true,
              }),
              new TextRun({
                text: "\tGithub is the best",
                bold: true,
              }),
            ],
          }),
        ],
      },
    ],
  });

  try {

    const blob = await Packer.toBlob(doc);
    console.log(blob);
    saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
    console.log("Document created successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

The network tab shows the following message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iom6E.png)

My question: is it even possible to create and save a local file in an Office Add-in (e.g., Excel Add-in)? If not, what is the reason and is there a workaround?

I tried both fs and file-savers library to save and download a file, but as far as I know nothing is being saved and there is no error message in console.

Comment: You could likely save to remote server that is available to end users, but not local file system.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in an Office add-in. Add-ins are web apps and they face the same security restrictions as web apps. One of those restrictions is that web apps cannot access the local file system of the computer, except for certain highly constrained uses such as saving cookies. Libraries like fs are used in local Nodejs instances, not in web applications.